# Is there a way to limit the execution time of regex evaluation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex-lookarounds

I want to limit the execution time of the evaluation of a regex in javacript to 1 second (as a part of a series of steps aiming to mitigate [attacks on regex](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS)). Is there a way to do this in javascript (for example, make the evaluator return false upon timeout)?

Comment: In browser? Or server-side?

Comment: Flagged as duplicate assuming it's server side, if it's client side then it's not really an attack vector for a ReDoS attack in the first place.

Comment: It's for both client and server side. Why wouldn't it be a problem on client side?

Comment: @omer client side browsers can only be frozen at worst. If it's based on users own input it's a non issue since he's freezing his own browser only. If for some uncommon design reason a user can "share" his regex which in turn can be used by other users then yes those others users will fall victim. I would recommend running the regex server side in that scenario.